# using something other than *for* loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have this code i'm using for my bot and the point of the code is to give role on reaction but refer to **reactionRolesDict** for the information,
i have a bit of the code that i want to change but mainly the first **for** loop `for category in reactionRolesDict:` to something else because it makes the code execute once for every category in the dict.

this is the code:

```
reactionRolesDict = {
  gender_roles_id: {
    "emotes": ["♂️", "♀️"],
    "roles": [male_role, female_role],
    "exclusive": True
  },
  ping_roles_id: {
    "emotes": ["", "", "", "", ""],
    "roles": [announcements_role, giveaway_role, events_role, server_update_role, other_role],
    "exclusive": False
  }
)



@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

  for category in reactionRolesDict:

    if payload.message_id == reaction_gender_roles_id: 
      print('''this prints as many times as there is categories in *reactionRolesDict*''')

      category = reactionRolesDict[category]

      if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:

        role = category["roles"][category["emotes"].index(payload.emoji.name)]
        member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

        if category["exclusive"]:

          for has_role in category["roles"]:

            if has_role in member.roles:

              print('member has a role from the same category')

              return

          await member.add_roles(role)
```

edit: removed unnecessary parts of the code

Comment: And do you have any requirements on what the something else should do? Perhaps you can exchange `for` and the first if statement since it is independent of the category.

Comment: You haven't said what you actually _want_.  Okay, you don't want to loop once for every category.  What should the code do instead?

Comment: ... Just remove the for loop?

Comment: yeah, sorry if i wasn't clear about it. basically i want to change the `for` loop to `if` statment or something that would serve the code better. unfortunately i tried removing the `for` loop but it breaks it

Comment: It's still not clear what this is supposed to do. But maybe you just want to use a variable as the key of `reactionRolesDict`? So do something with `reactionRolesDict[someVariable]`?

Comment: i'm gonna be honest, i didn't write this code and i don't know much about python, all i cared about is that it works; i was looking at your comment for a hot minute and i couldn't understand what you meant

Comment: "because it makes the code execute once for every category in the dict" and *what* do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alot of people didn't understand what you meant, i believe that you want to hard code for every category, if that's the case then i would not recommend you do it that way because the code you have right now serves all categories by it self without the need of repeating.

nevertheless this is the hard coded version of the code (of which i don't recommend)

```
reactionRolesDict = {
  gender_roles_id: {
    "emotes": ["♂️", "♀️"],
    "roles": [male_role, female_role],
    "exclusive": True
  },
  ping_roles_id: {
    "emotes": ["", "", "", "", ""],
    "roles": [announcements_role, giveaway_role, events_role, server_update_role, other_role],
    "exclusive": False
  }
)



@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

  for category in reactionRolesDict:

    if payload.message_id == gender_roles_id: 
      print('''this prints as many times as there is categories in *reactionRolesDict*''')

      category = reactionRolesDict[category]

      if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:

        role = category["roles"][category["emotes"].index(payload.emoji.name)]
        member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

        if category["exclusive"]:

          for has_role in category["roles"]:

            if has_role in member.roles:

              print('member has a role from the same category')

              return

          await member.add_roles(role)



    if payload.message_id == ping_roles_id: 
      print('''this prints as many times as there is categories in *reactionRolesDict*''')

      category = reactionRolesDict[ping_roles_id]

      if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:

        role = category["roles"][category["emotes"].index(payload.emoji.name)]
        member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

        if category["exclusive"]:

          for has_role in category["roles"]:

            if has_role in member.roles:

              print('member has a role from the same category')

              return

          await member.add_roles(role)
```

i do not recommend you do this at all but it's there if you want to hard code it